# Nginx + PHP-FPM redirect to static PHP file

Tags: php, nginx, static, fpm

Some details about my setup first:

- I am serving a static webapp (HTML + JS) from default Nginx webroot
- I have a PHP-FPM server running on localhost:9000
- The destination file should be /api/webroot/index.php for FPM (**always**, no need to try_files etc.)
- I need to forward all **/api** and **/api-debug** calls to arrive at localhost:9000, and the /app/webroot/index.php should handle all these requests.

I have the following **working** Nginx configuration:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server localhost:9000;
    keepalive 30;
}

server {
    listen   80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        location ~ ^/(api|api-debug)/ {
            root       /app/webroot;
            index      index.php;
            try_files  $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/api\/)(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /app/webroot/$fastcgi_script_name;

                include        fastcgi_params;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to make it more simple and efficient, because as I see it now it's a mess.
I tried to adjust for example

> try_files  $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args;

to

> try_files  $uri /api/webroot/index.php$is_args$args;

and it failed... The only reason that it works is that /api/index.php includes /api/webroot/index.php, but I see it's inefficient.

I found debugging nginx config hard, because it's not easy to test.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: According to your question, `index.php` is located at `/app/webroot/index.php`. But according to your **working** configuration file, the URI `/api/index.php` would resolve to a pathname of `/app/webroot/api/index.php`. Adding `webroot` to the URI make no sense, what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for the response. Both files exist: /app/index.php and /app/webroot/index.php, where /app/index.php is just an include statement for /app/webroot/index.php.

Please note that the files are located on the disk at **/app/xxx** and **NOT** at **/api/xxx**. The /api/ is just the URL.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to get this working: [CakePHP docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#nginx)
With the following:
- The rewrite rules only apply to URL-s starting with /api
- The files are not available on the nginx server's host (try_files will fail, I also don't see any need for it, just pass all /api requests to localhost:9000/app/webroot/index.php in the proper rewrite form)

Hope I made some clarification here.
Thanks for your help! @RichardSmith

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice the `fastcgi_split_path_info` removing the `/api/` prefix from the URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to hardwire SCRIPT_FILENAME with a value of `/app/webroot/index.php` and remove one of your `location` blocks altogether.

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ ^/(api|api-debug)/ {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /app/webroot/index.php;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
}
```

---

Alternatively, to keep the flexibility of specifying a URI with a `.php` extension, you could simplify the configuration with:

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    rewrite ^/(api|api-debug)/ /index.php last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /app/webroot$uri;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'll try this tomorrow and report back!

Comment: Hi Richard, the calls to /api end up correctly at PHP-FPM, but I have some rewrite issues, I pasted a diff of print_r($_SERVER); [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/RM8ciLew). Your config's results are on the left, my working config on the right. The only issue with mine is that I do not know how it works and I don't like things that way... Should I replace all variables with fastcgi_param hardwiring them? Or is there a cleaner solution? Thank you!

Comment: In the top example, the URI is not rewritten so all of the FastCGI parameters are derived from the original request. Also, `root` is not in scope, so contains the `nginx` default value. All of these parameters are defined in the `fastcgi_params` file, so you can override them with what your application needs, or use the bottom example.

Comment: Dear Richard, after several hours of debugging, I found exactly what the app needs. I didn't pay attention to this in detail earlier because I was using apache with pre-made .htaccess files shipped with the framework.
So it turns out that /api/some/path/here?sample=querystring should end up like this: /app/webroot/index.php/api/some/path/here?sample=querystring, and no other .php files will be processed ever, so no need for the second "location ~ \.php$" block (I guess?).
Could you help me out please to make this as clean and efficiant as possible? Thank you very much for your generous help!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that this should also work for /api-debug as well... Thank you once more!

Comment: I would also appreciate some idea or some phrases to look up if you have any @RichardSmith ! Thank you